# What is the best way to trim edges off of hardwood floor where wall was removed?

Tags: walls, floor, hardwood-floor

I have removed a wall from a closet that was backed up against another closet to make it a walk in. I would like to run hardwood perpendicular to the current pattern in the gap where the wall was.

I will need to trim the uneven ends on the existing flooring to get a clean finish, what is the best way to to this? I was thinking a circular saw...
Also how can I clean the black off the existing floor after trimming? 
Is this even a good idea? Thanks for the feedback.

[image: floor where wall was removed]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably also go for the circular saw.
Make sure to use a variable depth circular saw and to set it to the same thickness as the existing floor boards, so you only trim them and nothing beneath them.
Then for the last pieces next to the wall where the circular blade won't reach you could use a hammer and a chisel to knock the last bit off.

As to the blackness:
Assuming you'll want to have the "filling" boards blend in with the existing floors, I'd advise to sand the whole floor and re-varnish/wax the floor.
The blackness is most likely dirt or a moisture stain that has built up over the years, when sanding give these spots special attention to make sure you sand them off but just make sure not to go too deep.
My parents have a rosewood floor and once every couple of years they sand the whole floor and apply new wax to it, afterwards it looks brand new.

Comment: Use a finish blade to minimize tearout. You could screw a board to the subfloor to act as a guide fence.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I may just cut that black area out...

Comment: Personally I'd try to sand it first. If it hasn't penetrated too deep it would be a waste of effort and wood to replace it off the bat.